# Why is my tkinter app closing without error message only the second time the update command is run?

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter

I'm working on a tkinter GUI to display images from certain directories. The GUI features a plot button that updates the image. In the fully-functional GUI, the image can be updated with a variety of changes, including image source, but the example below does not include this and plots only an identical image. The plot function uses a matplotlib Figure and a tk Canvas to return an object that can be gridded, as well as the original Figure for the purpose of garbage collection.

The second time the plot function is called, the GUI closes without any error message. In the example below, the plot function is used on init, then again when the button is pressed. However, I've tried it with a simplified plot function on init (shown below the example), and the GUI only closes when the real plot function is operated the second time.

```
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.figure import Figure 
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import (FigureCanvasTkAgg,
                                               NavigationToolbar2Tk)

def plot_image(img_path, root, ratio=2.0):
    '''
    Plots image using plt.imshow and tk.Canvas
    
    Input:
        -img_path: string, filepath to plt.imread-acceptable source
        -root: root Tk object for returned widget
        -ratio: float, aspect ratio (W:H)
    Output:
        -tuple: (tkinter Canvas of plt Figure, plt subplot)
    
    Note: plt subplot garbage collection must be handled on application end
    '''
    # Create image
    img = Image.open(img_path)
    img_arr = np.asarray(img)
    
    # Create plot
    fig = Figure()
    base_size = 2.5
    fig, plot1 = plt.subplots(1, subplot_kw={'aspect': 'auto'},
                    figsize=(ratio*base_size, base_size))
    xleft, xright = plot1.get_xlim()
    ybottom, ytop = plot1.get_ylim()
    plot1.set_aspect(abs((xright-xleft)/(ybottom-ytop))*ratio)
    plot1.imshow(img_arr, rasterized=True, aspect='auto')

    # Return tk.Canvas
    canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master=root)
    canvas.draw()
    canvas = canvas.get_tk_widget()
    return (canvas, fig)

class UI(tk.Frame):
    '''
    Frame for displaying a single image
    '''
    def __init__(self, master, **options):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master, **options)
        self.img_path = "image.png"
        self.wgt_img, self.img = plot_image(self.img_path, self)
        self.wgt_img.grid(row=0, column=0)
        btn_load = tk.Button(self, text="Load",
                             command=lambda: self.update_image())
        btn_load.grid(row=1, column=0)

    def update_image(self):
        self.wgt_img.grid_forget()
        plt.close(self.img)
        self.wgt_img, self.img = plot_image(self.img_path, self)
        self.wgt_img.grid(row=0, column=0)

def run():
    root = tk.Tk()
    gui = UI(root)
    gui.pack()
    root.mainloop()

run()
```

```
def load_image(img_path, root):
    '''
    Plots image using ImageTk.PhotoImage
    
    Input:
        -img_path: string, filepath to plt.imread-acceptable source
        -root: root Tk object for returned widget

    Output:
        -tuple: (tkinter Label, tkinter PhotoImage)
    '''
    img = Image.open(img_path)
    img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)
    return (tk.Label(root, image=img), img)
```

I've tried adding print statements to the functions. It appears to be able to exit the function, but crashes immediately after exiting. At this point I'm at a bit of a loss. I think it's something to do with using the Canvas instead of a Label, but I don't know beyond that. Any ideas?

Comment: Just a guess, but ``self.wgt_img.grid_forget()`` does not actually destroy the widget, but just removes it from the layout. Reassigning it two lines down might cause an unclean GC of the old ``wgt_img``.

Comment: Use `self.wgt_img.destroy()` instead of `self.wgt_img.grid_forget()`

Comment: @TorbenKlein that makes sense but it doesn't seem to have fixed it

Comment: as I said, just guessing. If I had been sure, I'd have posted it as answer... anyway, upvote for posting the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**

I got it working. The problem was that the Canvas depended on the Figure existing, so once the Figure was closed, the Canvas didn't have anything to display and closed itself. I'm not sure why there isn't an error message for that, but at least it works now. Edited code:

```
def update_image(self):
        self.wgt_img.destroy()
        old_img = self.img
        self.wgt_img, self.img = plot_image(self.img_path, self)
        plt.close(old_img)
        self.wgt_img.grid(row=0, column=0)
```